# Lambda groovy function List<Webelement> getText is not compiled

Tags: selenium, arraylist, groovy, lambda

I am trying to implement Groovy Lambda function but it is not correct what is written.
To get it very simple. Here is the java code that uses lambda.

```
protected void aaa(List<WebElement> el){
    el.stream().filter(a->a.getText() == "a");
}
```

I used the similar approach

```
List<WebElement> list = ...
list.stream().filter(a->a.getText() == "a")
```

It is not compiled due to the error: Unexpected token ->...

Can anybody please provide a description and example how to get it in Groovy?

Comment: What is your Groovy version?

Comment: I am using Katalon Studio, but version used is 1.0.0.201807120458

Comment: This is very old version. In versions 2.* (don't know if all of them) you can use closure instead of the lambada.

Comment: Can you provide an example for closure for List<WebElement> ? I can try to update to newer.

Comment: Sorry, it uses org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.7.xx-201611170128-e46 version

Comment: I posted an answer.

Comment: Thank you for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy [stable version 2.5.1](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) doesn't support Java lambadas. Version 2.6 and later does. With last version you can use closure instead

```
list.stream().filter( { a -> a.getText() == "a" } )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.Please can you help me to groovy this line:
list.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
Mine version fails:
list.stream().map({ WebElement } as String).collect(Collectors.toList())
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.map() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [quality1.CommonMethods$_clickSubMenuLeftBar_closure2@4e49ce2b]
Possible solutions: map(java.util.function.Function), max(java.util.Comparator), min(java.util.Comparator), wait(), grep(), any()

Comment: @Michal Please ask a new question, the comments aren't meant for this.

Comment: Ok,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634927/get-text-from-listwebelement-in-groovy