# Get text from List<WebElement> in Groovy

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I am dealing with problem to implement groovy lambda function getting text from List collection into List collection.
The original java code:

```
list.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My Groovy version fails:

```
list.stream().map({ WebElement } as String).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.map() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [quality1.CommonMethods$_clickSubMenuLeftBar_closure2@4e49ce2b]
>   Possible solutions: map(java.util.function.Function),
>   max(java.util.Comparator), min(java.util.Comparator), wait(), grep(),
>   any() –

Can anybody help me how to make it working? I was trying to use similar approach like here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/04/groovy-goodness-use-closures-as-java.html but without success.

Comment: why not just `list.collect { it.text }`?

Answer (score 0):

Groovy 3.0 *(current version: 3.0.0-alpha-3)* will support lambda expressions and method references thanks to a new parrot parser - http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html

For Groovy 2.5.x and older you will have to replace method reference:

```
WebElement::getText
```

with a closure:

```
{ el -> el.getText() }
```

Final working example should look like this:

```
list.stream().map{ el -> el.getText() }.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Hello, thanks @Szymon, it gives: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Collectors for class: quality1.CommonMethods
The working solution is if I remove the parms in collect():
list.stream().map({a -> a.getText()}).collect()

Comment: @Michal You have to add import `import java.util.stream.Collectors` or use full canonical name in `.collect(java.util.streal.Collectors.toList())`